# 6TB HFS+ Raid will not mount

Tags: raid, hfs+

I want to connect my extrenal HFS+ formated Raid 5 6TB to Ubuntu.
It shows the drive on the desktop, but when I click on it, it say the 6TB Volume is to big to mount.

Answer (score 3):

> The Linux kernel includes the hfsplus module for mounting HFS+ filesystems. HFS+ fsck and mkfs have been ported to Linux and are part of the hfsprogs package.
>
> In 2009, these drivers were diagnosed to be corrupting HFS+ drives with a capacity greater than 2 TB. Consequently, Linux distributions such as Debian and Ubuntu also stopped allowing mounting of HFS+ drives or partitions greater than 2 TB. As of February 2011, work is in progress to lift this restriction.
>
> Under Linux's current HFS+ driver, journaling must be disabled in order to write data safely to an HFS+ partition; journaling can be disabled under Mac OS X, provided the partition isn't being used by Apple's Time Machine software. An HFS+ partition with journaling enabled may be forcibly mounted with write-access under Linux, but this is unsupported and unsafe.
>
> Around April 2011, Netgear released the source code of one of its NAS appliances, providing an implementation of write-support for journaling-enabled HFS+ partitions; unfortunately, the code is compatible only with an earlier version Linux. A port to newer versions of Linux has been released for review and further development, though it is apparently untested and untrustworthy.

<sup>Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)</sup>

Comment: Isn't quoting Wikipedia and nothing else almost as bad as link-only answers? I know it *does* answer the question, but... ?